# Multiple Pandas Pivot Table in Excel Sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, printing, pivot-table

I've written some codes to create 3 different pivot tables. They work perfectly when I want to print them in the Python Console.
However when I want to display in the my Excel Sheet, the code only show the last Pivot Table (table 3).
I didn t find anything in the Documentation "to excel" or "Pivot Table" about that to print the 3 pivot table in excel at the same time without delete the rest.

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(NewTransition_file)
df = xl.parse('DB - Jan - Dec',column=['A:AH'])
pd.read_excel(data)

Table1 = df.loc[df['Repricing Method'] == "Table1"]
Table1 = Table1.pivot_table(index=['Client Company Name'],values=['Original Total Charge','Provider Discount', 'Client Fees','Network Fee'])
Table1.to_excel(data, sheet_name='Table1',startcol=0, startrow=1)


Table2 = df.loc[df['Repricing Method'] == "Table2"]
Table2= Table2.pivot_table(index=['Client Company Name'],values=['Original Total Charge','Provider Discount', 'Client Fees','Network Fee'])
Table2.to_excel(data, sheet_name='Table2', startcol=6, startrow=1)

Table3 = df.loc[df['Repricing Method'].isin(OtherMethod)]
Table3 = other.pivot_table(index=['Client Company Name'], values=['Original Total Charge','Provider Discount', 'Client Fees','Network Fee'])
Table3.to_excel(data, sheet_name='Table3', startcol=11, startrow=1)
```

Comment: Concat them before writing to excel. See `pd.concat`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Table3 overwrites the others I guess. Use [ExcelWriter](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) from pandas instead.

Comment: Thanks, I am now able to write my 3 pivots but that's still overwrite the other sheets.

Comment: Did you use mode=“a” for append like the last example shows?

Comment: Yes I used it, but it still delete my other sheets

Answer (score 0):

Use below , mode is 'a' append and startrow = where you want your pivot table to start in same sheet

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('some_excel.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:
    pivot_1_df.to_excel(writer,startrow= 0 ,sheet_name='Pivots')
    pivot_2_df.to_excel(writer,startrow= 8 ,sheet_name='Pivots') # starts from 8th  row
```

make sure pandas is upto date or update using

```
pip install pandas --upgrade
```